# Wordpress 2 column page not working

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem with one of my wordpress blogs.

The page has two columns side by side, when I click '*edit the page*' and put the code and content in on 'html mode' but when I switch to visual mode and change anything, the column breaks up and the right half goes underneath the first( ontop of each other rather than side by side).

I've added 'display:inline-block' and 'float:left' ect to the CSS but it still doesn't stay where it is meant to. Does anyone have any ideas on how to keep the columns in place when editing between html and visual mode. (and i do want to use visual mode)

also to note-
**my php template:**

```
 <article class="col-1">
 <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
 <div class="post">
  <div class="entrytext">
  <?php the_content('<p class="serif">Read the rest of this page &raquo;</p>'); ?> 
  <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
  <?php edit_post_link('Edit this entry.', '', ''); ?>                   
  </article>
   <div class="clear"></div>
             <div class="clear"></div>
             <article class="col-2">
             </article>
```

### then get footer

In my **page** I have put in column 1's content
then a line after I put this:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
            </article>
            <article class="col-2">
```

### then column 2's content

any idea's on how to solve this problem?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try 'clear: both;'

Seems like a css problem.

Comment: I have a div already called "clear" with a css rule of clear:both. any other ideas to why the column is changing when i edit it in visual editor? thanks

Comment: afraid not, il try and describe it best i can; ive put the contents in the html side and the client wants to edit it by visual editor only, but when they do that, it strips out <article="column-2"> out (the layout basically). any ideas?